# Naviers Stokes equation and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

I am looking for a reference explaining how to solve Navier-Stokes numerically using Machine learning algorithms .

Thank you in advance for your help .

Comment: We'll probably need more context.  Why do you think that machine learning is a good way to solve Navier-Stokes?  It sounds counter-intuitive.  Did you come across this idea somewhere?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88698/755, https://mathoverflow.net/q/294017.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.